# Change background color for matching parentheses PyCharm Editor

Tags: pycharm, editor

In PyCharm Editor, whenever I place the caret beside a parentheses (small brackets like these) or at square brackets, the matching bracket is highlighted with blue color. While coding, I inadvertently pressed on something and this color changed to gray. It looks very ugly and I'm not able to concentrate on coding :'-)
How can I change that back to blue? Anywhere I can reset it? I looked in `Seetings>Editor>Color Scheme`, but couldn't find how to change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matched Brace is the name of the Colour Setting for this

[image]